# Editing registry keys with Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

I am trying to force Teamviewer to go to systray after clicking "close=x" on the window.

Somehow this changes reg but doesn't thick that in Teamviewer options.

Anyone have a solution for that?

```
$regkey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer"   
set-itemproperty -path $regkey -name MinimizeToTray -Value 1
```

Comment: Are you sure you should be doing this in `HKLM:`, not `HKCU:`? and are you sure it is inside key `Wow6432Node` ?

Comment: I tried changing the value for local and also for current user (HKLM and HKCU)
somehow it just doesn't do what it's supposed to do.

$regkey = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\TeamViewer"
new-itemproperty -path $regkey -name MinimizeToTray -Value 1


$regkey = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\TeamViewer"
set-itemproperty -path $regkey -name MinimizeToTray -Value 1